# adding .rotatable to object returns its initial degree to 0

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, rotation

adding .rotatable to object returns its initial degree to 0

I have made a Code Pen where I insert the HTML via jquery and when I make them `rotatable` they lose their angle [link](https://codepen.io/KhAzZaKa/pen/WNxzPVY)

For example, if I have a div with `class= box` when I make this div `rotatable` using `$('.box').rotatable();`  this library adds `ui-rotatable` class to the `div` and adds the handle div

```
<div class="ui-rotatable-handle" unselectable="on" style="user-select: none; position: absolute; width: 9px; height: 9px; top: 0px; left: 0px; cursor: grab;"></div>
```

so the complete result shows as follows (after rotating the div with class box 180 degrees it have this as a style `transform: rotate(180deg);`)

```
<div class="box ui-rotatable" style="transform: rotate(180deg);">
Text rotate
<div class="ui-rotatable-handle" unselectable="on" style="user-select: none; position: absolute; width: 9px; height: 9px; top: 0px; left: 0px; cursor: grab;"></div>
```

Now that I have this code, I want to insert it on startup so the div takes 180degrees and can be rotated so I created a div `container` and using jquery I injected the div box to it `$("#container").html(content);`

at this point, the div is rotated 180 degrees but it is not rotatable, so I used `$('.box').rotatable();` to make it rotatable again but now the div returned to 0 degrees.

I have searched within the code to find if something it resetting the degree but couldn't find it especially that it is taking as far as I can tell the original degree with this code `instance.elementCurrentAngle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning back and inspecting the code closely I found that the `_angle` function is receiving and `angle` of value `0` and that function invokes the `perform` function with the angle of value 0 so I disabled the function `return`

```
 _angle: function(angle) {
            this.elementCurrentAngle = this._calculateAbsoluteAngle(this._num(angle));
            // return this.perform(this.element, this.elementCurrentAngle);
        },
```

Now that the angle isn't received as a 0 the old angle is used.